# GitHub Actions: Installing NumPy before other dependencies

Tags: python, numpy, github-actions, workflow

I have a workflow on GitHub that is performing unit tests with `pytest`.

One of the dependencies in `requirements.txt` requires `NumPy` to be already present, since it is using `numpy.distutils` in its `setup.py` to install some Fortran extensions. I therefore need to install `NumPy` before the other dependencies.

My `workflow.yaml` file looks as follows

```
name: unit_tests

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        python-version: ["3.8", "3.9", "3.10", "3.11"]
        os: [ubuntu-latest, windows-latest, macos-latest]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v4
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
    - name: Installing Numpy
      run: |
        pip install pip --upgrade
        pip install numpy
    - name: Installing requirements
      run: |
        pip install flake8 pytest
        pip install -r requirements.txt
    - name: Lint with flake8
      run: |
        # stop the build if there are Python syntax errors or undefined names
        flake8 . --count --select=E9,F63,F7,F82 --show-source --statistics
        # exit-zero treats all errors as warnings. The GitHub editor is 127 chars wide
        flake8 . --count --exit-zero --max-complexity=10 --max-line-length=127 --statistics
    - name: Test with pytest
      run: |
        pytest
```

All steps until and including "Installing Numpy" work so far:

```
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.24.3-cp310-cp310-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (19.8 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 19.8/19.8 MB 11.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.24.3
```

But the step "Installing requirements" fails with the error

```
× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [17 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.11/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.11/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.11/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/private/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-67g_j2me/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "/private/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-67g_j2me/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/private/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-67g_j2me/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
        File "/private/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-67g_j2me/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
      [end of output]
```

Indicating that `NumPy` is not present.

All Python versions and operating systems have the same error.
What can I do to have `NumPy` already installed and available when the other requirements are installed?

I am not sure if that makes a difference, but `NumPy` is also present in `requirements.txt`.

Comment: Does it make a difference when you remove it from requirements.txt? And I'd install wheel before installing Numpy.

Comment: Thank you! Installing wheel before numpy helped.

The Ubuntu tests now run through. The MacOS tests still fail during installation, but his time because no Fortran compiler is available. The Windows tests fail during the test phase, because the Fortran modules could not be imported, although the installation worked. I guess these are other issues.

Do you have an explanation why installing wheel worked? I'm trying to understand what is going on under the hood.

Comment: Great to read that! And: Hard to answer directly, I can only say why I suggested to install wheel before Numpy: Practical knowledge. When I'm doing pip based installations, before I pull in the requirements I install wheel first because normally wheel is not part of the requirements but pip might want to use it to install a requirement. Therefore I always put it very early. Similar to put pip update first, to benefit from pip improvements (this can bite you occasionally, but is normally fine).