# Unable to install fbprophet in gitlab CI

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, setup.py, facebook-prophet, prophet

I committed/pushed a minor change but my pipeline is failing - seems to be a prophet install issue, specifically

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

....

```
Running setup.py install for fbprophet did not run successfully.
```

It ran fine earlier and also when I run the python tox command locally but fails in gitlab CI. I have tried doing pip install numpy before the tox command but it did not make a difference. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Only remotely reminds me to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76292039/367456

Comment: unfortunately the solution in the post doesn't help :(